# Is there any particular reason to store user's timezone when I have already stored user's local time and UTC time - PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering why should i need to store user's timezone as many suggested when I have two columns already in my db table `local_datetime` and `utc_datetime` which are used  to show how long ago a comment was posted. I can use the `utc_datetime` and convert it to user's local time and the `local_datetime` helps me sorting results by a particular day for a user. So my question is, what is the purpose of storing timezone??

Comment: If you have the `utc_datetime` field, how do you convert it to user's local time without having the timezone of the user?

Comment: Using JS in client side :) @Progman

Answer (score 1):

When you stored user's UTC time, it does not require any other parameters. That moment was same allover the world. If you want to know where that user came from, only then you need to store his/her timezone. Your use case seems to just calculate elapsed time you can do it by generating the time difference from stored UTC time and current UTC time.

Comment: Got it. So, there is no need to store timezone unless i have something to do with the location.